# IIS has no websites

Tags: iis, windows-10

I'm configuring Windows 10 machine for web development. Installed Visual Studio and want to configure websites. Installed IIS manager but for some reason it doesn't have... anything. No websites, no application pools, no features at all. And it doesn't let me to add any of that.
Has anyone faced this kind of behavior?
[image]

Comment: check your installed windows features.

Comment: Which one? As I said, IIS Manager is installed.

Comment: I have them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It turned out that something messed up IIS config files (in Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config). So all IIS features were referencing invalid DLLs in the GAC and therefore were silently failing. I only found a trace of that in the Windows Event Log.
Took clean administration.config file and IIS started correctly.

Comment: I request you to mark the post as an answer it helps helo other people who face a similar issues.